# Apache Kafka Topic equivalent in Azure Event Hub

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, azure-eventhub

When we look at the default Azure Event Hub we have `Event Hub Namespaces` and we have the possibility to create `Event Hubs` within those Namespaces. In `Apache Kafka` you have `Topics`.

Is `Topic` the same as an `Event Hub` within an `Event Hub Namespace`?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-for-kafka-ecosystem-overview#kafka-and-event-hub-conceptual-mapping

Comment: Yep, thats it. Perfect! Can you please create an answer and copy the table into the answer for the case that the page isnt accessible in the future. I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an overview of the Kafka and Event Hub conceptual mapping:

**Kafka Concept**   **Event Hubs Concept**

| Kafka Concept | Event Hubs Concept |
| --- | --- |
| Cluster | Namespace |
| Topic | Event Hub |
| Partition | Partition |
| Consumer Group | Consumer Group |
| Offset | Offset |

([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-for-kafka-ecosystem-overview#kafka-and-event-hub-conceptual-mapping))

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate that!